# Disallow virtual package in Debian's /etc/apt/preferences

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I know I can disallow a particular package in Debian by appending `/etc/apt/preferences` with:

```
Package: *x11*
Pin: release
Pin-Priority: -1
```

But how can I do that for a *virtual* package like `httpd`? I'd like to disallow installation of *all* packages that provide this [virtual `httpd`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/httpd) but the one selected by me. Is there a (simple) way to do this?

The reason: recently, an automatic `apt-get dist-upgrade` removed `nginx` and installed `lighttpd` instead, because some other package (`phppgadmin` *AFAIR*) depended on `httpd` and something `nginx` **started** depending on in that update was not installable. I'd really like the whole upgrade to fail in this case, rather than put the http service down. Also: is it possible to make a package "uninstallable"? That would be a good solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather build a tiny meta-package with [equivs](https://packages.debian.org/equivs) with according `Conflicts` and maybe `Depends`. That allows more fine-grained control over which package needs to be installed and which may not be installed.

Pinning is more for picking the right version of a package (and until very recently, virtual package couldn't have a version) and not to install one or another package -- although that should be possible in theory.

Another possibility is to use a tool which keeps all packages in a list installed or uninstalled, e.g. [aptitude-robot](https://packages.debian.org/aptitude-robot). (There may be others, but aptitude-robot is what I use for that.) aptitude-robot though only applies your configured package lists when it is used to upgrade packages, it doesn't apply to normal `aptitude` or `apt-get` runs.

If you only use `aptitude`, a third possibility may be to use Aptitude's `forbid-version` (Shift-F) feature in a situation as in your example. This though won't apply if you later use `apt-get` again.